# Razor pages linter is not working on VsCode .NET 6 C# extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, razor

when i open vscode Razor pages i get this error
The Razor Language Server server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted.

```
Razor.VSCode version 6.0.0-preview.5.21358.6
```

Razor's trace level is currently set to 'Off'

- To change Razor's trace level set 'razor.trace' to 'Off', 'Messages'
  or 'Verbose' and then restart VSCode.
- To report issues invoke the'Report a Razor issue' command via the
  command palette.

here is the logs output

> Cannot get required symbol EVP_MD_size from libssl
> [Info - 2:39:23 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
> [Error - 2:39:23 AM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
> Error: Connection got disposed.
> at Object.dispose (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:994214)
> at Object.dispose (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:1050936)
> at x.handleConnectionClosed (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:1051111)
> at x.handleConnectionClosed (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:1070276)
> at t (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:1049310)
> at n.invoke (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:979052)
> at r.fire (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:979782)
> at $ (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:986274)
> at n.invoke (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:979052)
> at r.fire (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:979782)
> at t.StreamMessageWriter.fireClose (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:999879)
> at Socket. (/home/muchirajunior/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-linux-x64/dist/extension.js:2:1000249)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
> at Pipe. (node:net:687:12)

Comment: issue open on GitHub here https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5347

Comment: Error says "Cannot get required symbol EVP_MD_size"  See : https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5321?force_isolation=true